# How to use Resources from app and Android library module in the same Java class

Tags: java, android, namespaces, android-resources, android-library

I want to extract resources into an Android library.
I have a Java class which needs to access Resources from **both**, the main app **and** from the library.

### Example

```java
import com.myapp.R;

public class IconSupport {

  public static int getAppDrawable() {
      // this resource is in the app module
      return R.drawable.special_app_icon;
    }

  public static int getLibraryDrawable() {
      // this resource is in the library module
      return R.drawable.library_info_icon;
    }

}
```

This code will **not** work, because I imported `com.myapp.R` but want to access `library_info_icon` which is in `com.mylibrary.R`

Note that the resource files have different names, so this is **not** a name conflict that could be solved be prefixing the library resources like [suggested in the Android library documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations)

I know that there is **no import Aliasing in Java**, so I can not give the library resources a different namespace.

**So, how do I solve this issue?  Android Libraries are meant to extract resources like that and using them in the same file could not be such a special case. What am I missing?**

Comment: You don't _have_ to use `import` statements. Just use the fully qualified name(s) where needed.

Comment: That's indeed a solution for this! Thanks. Nevertheless this really blows up the code. I can not image that there is not a more elegant/better to read solution to this. But for now this solves my problem. Thank you!